# bash - Mac OS X - how to run an application as multiple users?

Tags: bash, macos, ssh, applescript

I need to run the same application (cocoa native, not X11) with multiple instances (different credentials) at the same time.

I'm testing on a Mac OS X Sierra and different Skype accounts (any cocoa app is good for testing). So I created 2 additional OS X users, in order for the userspace to be segregated: u01 and u02, plus the main user.

From the main user's desktop I open the terminal:

`sudo su u01 -c /Applications/Skype.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes &`

Activity Monitor says that iTunes is running as u01, perfect.

`sudo su u02 -c /Applications/Skype.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes &`

Instead, this Skype instance becomes a subprocess of u01's Skype and u02 isn't present in Activity Monitor.

I tried with ssh -X, but it seems to work only with X11. Docker is headless and still bound on X11 (not considering the learning curve). Also tested without success: native sandbox, GNU parallel. I tried with RUNAS by Joseph Beeson on Sierra and it worked, but can't be automated from bash, isn't updated since 2011, doesn't work with newer OS X. Have you got any hint / workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tons of readings and several tries, I found a working solution.

RunAs by Joseph Beeson was working Until OS X Sierra / High Sierra. Also other developers made similar apps, but all of them didn't work anymore starting from Mojave. Probably this is the reason why these projects have been abandoned and also removed: you can't find these apps nowhere, even if you -like me- use Sierra / High Sierra.

After 2 months I succeeded in retrieving the original RunAs via WayBackMachine, here's the only link to download it: https://web.archive.org/web/20150630193356if_/http://josephbeeson.com/uploads/RunAs.zip

It's quite slow and not much customizable: it opens a dialog to select the app to be run and the user to run it, but with a bit of applescript I was able to fully automate it. Cheers to Joseph!